vba excel search with two criteria then update
Please I am having problem with userform to activate a sheet then searching with two criteria that is by year and month to populate other fields and then update.Kindly assist me.Thank you
I have tried to create two search text boxes to search by year and month so that when these criteria are met then it can populate the other fields.
I expect that when i activate the active sheet then search for year and month on the same row then populate other fields then update.
when i click the search command it point me to,Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Dim x As Integer
    ' Loop through months (1 to 12) and add them to ComboBox2
    With Me.ComboBox2
        For x = 1 To 12
            .AddItem MonthName(x)
        Next x
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim targetsheet As String
    targetsheet = ComboBox1.Value
    ' Check if targetsheet is empty, exit the sub if true
    If targetsheet = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Worksheets(targetsheet)
        Dim lastRow As Long
        ' Find the last row in column 1
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Fill in values from textboxes and combobox into the next row
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = TextBox3.Value
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = ComboBox2.Value
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = TextBox2.Value
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = TextBox4.Value
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 6).Value = TextBox5.Value
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = TextBox6.Value
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 10).Value = TextBox7.Value
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 12).Value = TextBox8.Value
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 13).Value = TextBox9.Value
        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 14).Value = TextBox10.Value
        MsgBox "Data was added successfully"
        ' Clear the values of input fields after data is added
        TextBox3.Value = ""
        ComboBox2.Value = ""
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        TextBox2.Value = ""
        TextBox4.Value = ""
        TextBox5.Value = ""
        TextBox6.Value = ""
        TextBox7.Value = ""
        TextBox8.Value = ""
        TextBox9.Value = ""
        TextBox10.Value = ""
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TextYear As Long
    Dim TextMonth As Integer
    Dim resultRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
    
    TextYear = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For TextMonth = 1 To 12
        resultRow = 0
        
        For i = 4 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = TextYear And ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = TextMonth Then
                ' Fill in textboxes with values from the found row
                TextYear = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                TextMonth = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
                TextBox1.Value = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
                TextBox2.Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
                TextBox4.Value = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
                TextBox5.Value = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
                TextBox6.Value = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
                TextBox7.Value = ws.Cells(i, 8).Value
                TextBox8.Value = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
                TextBox9.Value = ws.Cells(i, 10).Value
                TextBox10.Value = ws.Cells(i, 11).Value
                
                resultRow = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next TextMonth
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    ' Unload the UserForm1
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TextYear As Long
    Dim TextMonth As Integer
    Dim resultRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
    
    TextYear = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For TextMonth = 1 To 12
        resultRow = 0
        
        For i = 4 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = TextYear And ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = TextMonth Then
                ' Fill in textboxes with values from the found row
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = TextYear
                 ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = TextMonth
                 ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = TextBox1.Value
                 ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = TextBox2.Value
                 ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = TextBox4.Value
                 ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = TextBox5.Value
                 ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = TextBox6.Value
                 ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = TextBox7.Value
                 ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = TextBox8.Value
                 ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = TextBox9.Value
                 ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = TextBox10.Value
                resultRow = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next TextMonth
    MsgBox "Data was Updated successfully"
        ' Clear the values of input fields after data is added
        TextBox3.Value = ""
        ComboBox2.Value = ""
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        TextBox2.Value = ""
        TextBox4.Value = ""
        TextBox5.Value = ""
        TextBox6.Value = ""
        TextBox7.Value = ""
        TextBox8.Value = ""
        TextBox9.Value = ""
        TextBox10.Value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    ComboBox1.Clear
    ' Fill ComboBox1 with worksheet names from the workbook
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub


Are you getting an error message? Do you have a worksheet named "SheetName" ?

Yes it highlighted Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName"), but I do not have worksheet named SheetName. I wanted it to identify the active sheet

Then you might find Activesheet useful.

I have used Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("& ActiveSheet.Name") but still did not work.

Set ws = Activesheet   Also "did not work" is not a very useful description of what's going on when you run your code - please include the error message you're getting if you're having problems.

Please the error code is run- time '9' subscript out of range

Did you try my suggestion above?  Is the error on that line?

Yes please but is not working and not given any code

"not working and not given any code" I'm not able to make any suggestions based on this.  Exactly how is it not working?

The userform is not moving just stationery. finding way to send screenshot

Please screen shot link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dUl44YQq0_AuypZoszNTZYBs2Rlpxdj4/view?usp=drive_link

Your link isn't open...

Please try again https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dUl44YQq0_AuypZoszNTZYBs2Rlpxdj4/view?usp=drive_link

That's just a screenshot of your userform though?  What is that telling us?

Please, this is the link to the excel. Having problem with the search and update code. Thank you https://drive.google.com/file/d/14D0k9X9kGyCx0iia4EPvbWLZSL5ueOpw/view?usp=sharing

Your Search code has Set ws = ActiveSheet but the form is launched from MASTERSHEET, so ws will always be that sheet.  Also you have For TextMonth = 1 To 12 and then you test if ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = TextMonth which will never be true because TextMonth is 1,2,etc and ws.Cells(i, 2).Value is JANUARY, FEBRUARY, etc.
